# Find an orthogonal basis of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let's define dot procduct $<A,B>=Trace(A B^T)$ over $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$

Find basis or system of equations describing an orthogonal $W^\perp$ subspace to subspace $W$ which consist of matrices whose trace is $0$

I'd be greatful for any hints, since I don't know how to start this one

Comment: Hints: What is the dimension of $W$? Hence what must the dimension of $W^{\perp}$ be? Can you give an example of one (non-zero) element of $W^{\perp}$?

Comment: I think $\dim W= n^2-1$ so $\dim W^\perp = 1$ I'm not sure but an identity matrix can be in $W^\perp$ ?

Comment: And voilà, you're done!

Comment: But how do I finish? what is the basis ? just the identity matrix ?

Comment: Yes, that is what your previous comment shows!

Comment: Ok thanks a lot